# how to remove children in cocos2d, is there more that one way?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, side-scroller

Hello I am making a Cocos2d side scroller. I have a CCSprite that I add using the `[self addChild:sprite];` method. After a while I want the CCSprite to be removed. I tried the `[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];` method and it gave me a thread bad access error. Is this the only way to remove a child in Cocos2d?? Is there an alternate way?? I am a beginner to Cocos2d and objective c so any help is valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `removeChild:cleanup:` is the way to go if you need to remove any `CCNode`. Have you checked that `sprite` is not released before trying to remove it?

Comment: so in my app I want the character to move to the tiger so i have this code  CCMoveTo* moveToTheTiger = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(tiger.position.x + 90, tiger.position.y + 90)];
    [character runAction:moveToTheTiger];  but it makes another character so i have two characters on the screen. Why does this happen. i first create the character in the init method and then call another method which is where I tell the character to move.

Comment: Mmh not sure if I understand the problem. Are you getting two `character` sprites on screen where you would expect just one? If that's the case, chances are you're calling something like `[self addChild:character` twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanUp:YES]
```

If you have a bad access it means object is nill.
Check if your sprite exist before you try to remove it.